# import jwt ImportError: No module named jwt

Tags: python, jwt

I have been trying to run this project
https://github.com/udacity/FSND-Deploy-Flask-App-to-Kubernetes-Using-EKS

I installed all the dependencies.
I still did not make any adjustments. I need to run it first
but I get this error when I type the command

```
python main.py
```

this is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import jwt
ImportError: No module named jwt
```

I worked with similar errors before and managed to solve them but not with this one I could not figure out the source of the problem

Comment: UPDATE: for some reason when i worked in a virtual environment it worked just fine!!

Answer (score 20):

1. Check if PyJWTY is in the requirements file or if is installed in you system, using: **pip3 install PyJWT**
2. You could also face this error if you have running on your machine two versions of python. So the correct command will be **python3 main.py**

Comment: Installing using `pip3 install PyJWT` fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 5):

I have hit the same issue with pyjwt 2.1.0 which was clearly installed in my venv as well as globally. What helped was to downgrade it to version 1.7.1

`pip install "PyJWT==1.7.1"`

run the app and then to reinstall newest version 2.1.0

`pip install "PyJWT==2.1.0"`

And the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

This project has [requirements](https://github.com/udacity/FSND-Deploy-Flask-App-to-Kubernetes-Using-EKS/blob/master/requirements.txt) that need to be installed for it to work. These can be installed via pip, `pip install -r requirements.txt` (I've linked to the requirements file in the project), which you can read more about [here](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/).

Comment: hello thanks for answering i did install the requirements and checked that jwt is installed but still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was using `import jwt` instead of `import PyJWT`. I am using version PyJWT-2.3.0.

[jwt image on vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEBTG.png)
As you can see no errors in the above screenshot. The app runs without import errors.
[Image of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2ctl.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to have **only** `PyJWT` installed and not `JWT`. Make sure you uninstall `JWT` (`pip uninstall JWT`) and install `PyJWT` (`pip install PyJWT`)

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Am using a guest VM running ubuntu 16.04.
I have multiple versions of python installed - both 3.5 and 3.7.

After repeated tries with and without using virtualenv what worked finally is:

1. Create a fresh virtual environment using :
   priya:~$ **virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.7 fenv**
2. Activate the virutal environment :
   priya:~$ **source ./fenv/bin/activate**

Note : You can find the path for python3.7 by using whereis python:
priya:~$ **whereis python**
python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.5m /usr/bin/python3.5 **/usr/bin/python3.7** /usr/bin/python3.5m-config /usr/bin/python3.5-config /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/lib/python3.5 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.5 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.5m /usr/include/python3.5 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

Referenced link is : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20that%20will%20be,%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fpython3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20that%20will%20be,%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fpython3)

For your project - FSWD Nanodegree -
After you have activated your virtualenv, run pip install -r requirements.txt
You can test by :
(fenv) priya:FSND-Deploy-Flask-App-to-Kubernetes-Using-EKS :~$ python
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 18 2020, 06:24:24)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import jwt
> > > exit()

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install flask_jwt_ex.. I was doing this without sudo. And then I was working on the program as sudo.