# AWS Lambda works but Lambda@Edge throws error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda-edge, pyjwt

I have written a python lambda to redirect unauthorized users to Cognito. The lambda works when I run a test event in the lambda console, but when I try to hit the CloudFront distribution, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 
'pyjwt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I am not referring to pyjwt in my code. I am doing this `import jwt`, and I my lambda uses these packages. I have tried deleting the lambda@edge association and the lambda.

[image]

I'm completely stuck at this point. What can I try next?

Comment: Can you go thorough this GitHub issue on `pyjwt` and see if it helps? https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/issues/800

Comment: Answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63309591/1273882) may help you.

Comment: Very interested to find out what the issue is here. Please let us know, wish I could help... How did you deploy the lambda to both locations?

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be that all my packages needed to be in a `lib` folder for lambda@edge to find them. I found this answer on StackOverflow a little while ago, but I closed it and can't seem to find it again. The directory structure needs to be something like:

```
main_folder
--lib
----lib1
----lib2
----lib3
   function_handler.py
```